# Symfony Dynamic Forms with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

I am trying to do a form in which I will be able to add as many product options as I want (so collection with prototype). For this I need two fields, one Option Definition and second with Option values.

I have got entities like: Product, Options, Options Definitions and Product Options Join (I decided to use two ManyToOne instead of one ManyToMany, so in Product Definitions Join I got ManyToMany to Options and ManyToMany to Products).

When I am adding option to product, I want first to choose Option Definition and then update select box with Options. This is everything working alright, but the problem is that when I want to edit product then it is showing me default option definitions. For example, when I was creating product I added product with option definition size and the value of size was 40. When I going to edit product I am getting option definition color and size 40.

Here is on pictures what I mean:
[image]

And in second row there should be a Size instead of Colour.

Here you can also see how I got connected tables:
[image]

**ProductOptionsType Class**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $factory = $builder->getFormFactory();

    $builder
        ->add('optiondefinitions', 'entity', array(
                                'mapped' => false,
                                'class' => 'ePOS\ProductsBundle\Entity\OptionsDefinitions',
                                'query_builder' => function ($repository) { return $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')->orderBy('p.name', 'ASC'); },
                                'property' => 'name',
                                'attr' => array('class' => 'option-definitions'))) 
        ;

    $refreshOptions = function ($form, $option) use ($factory) {
        $form->add($factory->createNamed('options', 'entity', null, array(
            'class'         => 'ePOS\ProductsBundle\Entity\Options',
            'property'      => 'value',
            'label'         => false,
            'auto_initialize' => false,
            'query_builder' => function ($repository) use ($option) {
                                   $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('options')
                                                    ->innerJoin('options.optionDefinition', 'optionDefinitions');

                                   if($option instanceof OptionsDefinitions) {
                                       $qb = $qb->where('options.optionDefinition = :optiondefinitions')
                                                ->setParameter('optiondefinitions', $option);
                                   } elseif(is_numeric($option)) {
                                       $qb = $qb->where('options.id = :option_id')
                                                ->setParameter('option_id', $option);
                                   } else {
                                       $qb = $qb->where('options.optionDefinition = 1');
                                   }
                                   return $qb;
                               }
             )));
    };

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($refreshOptions, $factory) {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
        if (null === $data) {
            return ;
        }

        $refreshOptions($form, $data->getOptions()->getOptionDefinition());
    });

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($refreshOptions) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();

        if($data == null)
           $refreshOptions($form, null); //As of beta2, when a form is created setData(null) is called first

        if($data instanceof Location) {
            $refreshOptions($form, $data->getOptions()->getOptionDefinition());
            }
    });

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_BIND, function (DataEvent $event) use ($refreshOptions) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();

        if(array_key_exists('optiondefinitions', $data)) {
            $refreshOptions($form, $data['optiondefinitions']);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: is there a __toString() function in your class `ePOS\ProductsBundle\Entity\OptionsDefinitions` ?

Comment: Yes, I have added __toString() which is returning name of option definition.